# Is there a desktop code editor that is using ace?

Tags: ace-editor

I have been working on a tool that captures keystrokes in the ace editor and stores them for later use.

This has worked great in my web page prototype with ace. However, now I'd like to take the code that I have and use it with a desktop code editor that can change the local file system.

What desktop editors (that are extendable) use ace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zed and Cloud9 have nw.js based desktop versions. There are also several chrome apps like Caret

https://github.com/zedapp/zed
https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/running-cloud9-desktop
http://thomaswilburn.net/caret/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment no.
Ace is a code editor for the web written in JavaScript. There is no desktop version at the moment.
However you can use it online, access url is: https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html.
And later transfer or save your code to desktop when you are done.
Else use sublime: https://www.sublimetext.com